# Tsql compare two field in the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables : table_A and table_W. I want to get only the non-matching payment details with the corresponding descriptions. The table are:

table_W

```
adharno phone descrip_w amount_w
1       11    p1        100
2       22    p1        250
2       22    p2        250
2       22    p3        300
2       33    p1        150
2       33    p2        150
2       33    p3        400
3       55    p1        50
3       66    p1        100
```

table_A

```
adharno phone decrip_a  amount_a
1       11    p1        110
2       22    p1        150
2       22    p2        150
2       22    p3        400
2       33    p1        250
2       33    p2        250
2       33    p3        300
3       55    p1        100
3       66    p1        50
```

I am getting the following result.

```
adharno phone descrip_w amount_w decrip_a amount_a
1       11    p1        100      p1       110
2       22    p1        250      p1       150
2       22    p2        250      p2       150
2       22    p3        300      p3       400
2       33    p1        150      p1       250
2       33    p2        150      p2       250
2       33    p3        400      p3       300
3       55    p1        50       p1       100
3       66    p1        100      p1       50
```

But the result I am looking is as follows

```
adharno phone descrip_w amount_w decrip_a amount_a
1       11    p1        100      p1       110
```

I want to compare the matching `descrip`, even if the `phoneno` is different but the `adhaarno` should be same.

Comment: so .... what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT w.adharno,
       w.phone w_phone,
       descrip_w,
       amount_w,
       a.phone a_phone,
       decrip_a,
       amount_a
FROM table_w w
JOIN table_a a ON a.adharno = w.adharno
              AND w.descrip_w = a.decrip_a
              AND (w.phone <> a.phone
                OR w.amount_w <> a.amount_a)
```